# How to deploy liferay7 portlet to remote server by jenkins?

Tags: jenkins, gradle, ant, liferay

We have a Liferay7 project and need to deploy project to remote server by jenkins. I did the following items:

- Jenkins installed
- Checkout from git repository
- Build with Gradle 3.0

After that i need to deploy jar files to X.X.X.X server. What is the best practices for that? Should i deploy project with Ant or Gradle?

Comment: the technology is a matter of taste and sometimes depends upon the actual task it is used for.. i personally prefer creating docker images with the needed components i need, but even that must not be the right choice for your use case/working scheme

Comment: If you just want to deploy a portlet module for quick tests (not setup a portal bundle), you can also use the [Jenkins SSH/SCP Publish Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Publish+Over+SSH+Plugin) and copy the created artifact to the bundle deploy folder.